# What type of API or references/commands do I need when uploading a file and also connecting to a MongoDB from a Google Function?

Tags: python, mongodb, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, google-api-python-client

I'm now trying to make this simple Python script that will run when called through an API call or through a Google Function.  I'm very, very new to GCP and Python as I'm more familiar with Azure and PowerShell, but I need to know what I need to use/call in order to upload a file to a bucket and also read the file information, plus then connect to a MongoDB database.

Here is the flow of what I need to do:

1. API/function will be called with its URL and attached to it will be an actual file, like a seismic file type.
2. When the API/function is called, a Python script will run that will grab that file and upload it to a bucket.
3. Then I need to run commands against the uploaded file to retrieve items like "version","company","wellname", etc.
4. Then I want to upload a document, with all of these values, into a MongoDB database.

We're basically trying to replicate something we did in Azure with Functions and a CosmosDB instance.  There, we created a function that would upload the file to Azure storage, then retrieve values from the file, which I believe is the metadata of it.  After, we would upload a document to CosmosDB with these values.  It's a way of recording values retrieved from the file itself.  Any help would be appreciated as this is part of a POC I'm trying to present on!!  Please ask any questions!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your  questions:

#### Here's a code on how to [upload a file to a Cloud Storage bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-code-sample) using Python:

```
from google.cloud import storage


def upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name):
    """Uploads a file to the bucket."""
    # bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"
    # source_file_name = "local/path/to/file"
    # destination_blob_name = "storage-object-name"

    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)

    blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)

    print(
        "File {} uploaded to {}.".format(
            source_file_name, destination_blob_name
        )
    )
```

> Make sure that you have the Cloud Storage client library [installed on your requirements.txt](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-python). Example:
> **google-cloud-storage>=1.33.0**

#### To retrieve and view the object metadata here's the code and [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata#code-samples) as reference:

```
from google.cloud import storage


def blob_metadata(bucket_name, blob_name):
    """Prints out a blob's metadata."""
    # bucket_name = 'your-bucket-name'
    # blob_name = 'your-object-name'

    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.get_blob(blob_name)

    print("Blob: {}".format(blob.name))
    print("Bucket: {}".format(blob.bucket.name))
    print("Storage class: {}".format(blob.storage_class))
    print("ID: {}".format(blob.id))
    print("Size: {} bytes".format(blob.size))
    ...
```

#### Finally,

To connect to MongoDB using Python, here's a [sample project](https://github.com/feydan/python-mongo-example) which could help you understand how it works.